# Add to html pages in my project custom atribute that will be called by it self (like as data-bind)

Tags: javascript, html, durandal

I want to create custom attribute in my project, that will be called in the same moment that the "data-bind" attribute is calles.
I want you to understand me well, so please read my explaining:
I know how do create custom attribute and know how to use it. but the problem is, that my project has very many pages. I don't want that all team-member how will want to use my attribute (called "data-re"), to call my function.
I want that as same as the "data-bind" attribute is solved any-way, and you didn't have to call it each page, so I want to find place to write my code, that this code will be done every page without needing to write it specifily.
here is my code:

```
    <input type="text" data-re="value:40"/>


    function  compositionComplete(){ 

var dict = cacheManager.get(cacheItems.DICT);;

var reElms = document.querySelectorAll('[data-re]');
for (var n = 0; n < resElms.length; n++) {
    var reEl = reElms[n];
    if (n != 1) {

        var dataRe = reEl.getAttribute('data-re');
        while (dataRe) {
            var attr = dataRe;
            var cutPlace = dataRe.lastIndexOf(',');
            if (cutPlace >= 0) {
                attr = reKey.substring(cutPlace, dataRe.length - 1);
            }
            var reKey = attr.substring(attr.indexOf(':') + 1, attr.length);
            var attrName = attr.substring(0, attr.indexOf(':'));
            reEl[attrName] = dict[reKey].Descript;
            dataRe = dataRe.substring(attr.length, dataRe.length);
            if (cutPlace)
                dataRe = dataRe.substring(0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

my project is in durandal. till now the code behind the "data-re" attribute is in the "compositionComplete". I don't want to need to write anything about it in my pages! what should I do?
thank you,
Rut Nativ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use liveQuery and follow after each html element that added to your page:

```
   $("[data-res]").livequery(function () {
          your logic code...
   });
```